# Form values valid check don't work in aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to check my form values and return messeges using js.
where is my problem?

This is a part of my .aspx code:

```
    <form action="MyAccount.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return Form()" id="form">
        <input type="submit" value="שלח" class="input" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Contact.js"></script>
```

this is the Js:

```
function Form()
{
```

I've droped some lines here that creates the var using document.getelementbyID, they are all bool

```
if (flnmnull && phonenull && mailnull && sbjnull && txtnull && phonevalid && mailvalid)
    return true;
else
    Message(flnmnull, phonenull, mailnull, sbjnull, txtnull, phonevalid, mailvalid);
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.